# Access objects inside array Angular2

Tags: angular

i have a problem when I try to access to objects inside array. Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FirebaseService} from '../../services/firebase.service';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  listings:any;
  search:any;
  imageUrls: any = [];
  images:any;
  myimage:any;
  count:any;
  constructor(
    private firebaseService: FirebaseService,
    private router:Router,
    public af:AngularFire,
    private route:ActivatedRoute,    
    private flashMessage:FlashMessagesService) {
    
    this.firebaseService.getListings().subscribe(listings => {
      this.listings = listings;
      this.count = listings.length;
    });  
  }
  ngOnInit() {   

    this.firebaseService.getListings().subscribe(listings => { 


      this.listings = listings;
      for(var i = 0;i<this.listings.length;i++){
        this.getImageUrl(listings[i].$key);
      }

      console.log(this.imageUrls);
      console.log(this.imageUrls[1].ImageUrl);
    });  
  }
  searchProps(){    
    this.firebaseService.getListingsByTitle(this.search.toLowerCase()).subscribe(listings => { 
      this.listings = listings;
    });
  }

  getImageUrl(prodid){
    this.imageUrls = []; 
    this.firebaseService.getListingImages(prodid).subscribe(images => { 
      this.images = images[0];
      let image = images[0];
      let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
      let spaceRef = storageRef.child(image.path);
      storageRef.child(image.path).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
        // Set image url
        this.imageUrls.push(new ImageUrl(image.$key,url));        
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });        
      });
  }

}
export class ImageUrl {
  url: string;
  id:string;
  constructor(_id:string,_url: string) {
     this.url = _url
     this.id = _id;
  }
}
```

My console log is showing this but i can't access to this.imageUrls[0]:
[image]

I want to access to this.imageUrls[0] and get the url but says "undefined" I don't know why I can't do that. Please if someone can help me with this I am so stacked here.

## EDIT 13/06/2017

With the help from @JesúsPallares now is showing always the same image. Now I want for each listing the image. I paste here my front end code:

> ```
>     <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let listing of listings  | orderby:'!$key'"  >
>         <div class="card">
>             <div class="card-image">
>                 <img class="img-responsive" [src]="imgSelected">
>
>                 <span class="card-title">{{listing.title}}</span>
>             </div>
>             
>             <div class="card-content">
>                 <p>Cards for display in portfolio style material design by Google.</p>
>             </div>
>             
>             <div class="card-action">
>                 <a [routerLink]="['/listing/'+listing.$key]">+ Info</a>
>                 <a [routerLink]="['/listing/'+listing.$key]">Contacto</a>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> ```

Comment: `... this but i can't access to this.imageUrls[0]:` <= what happens (error compile time, error run time) and where are you trying to call this (template code in html, component, somewhere else)? Please review [ask] as well as [mcve] to help clarify your question.

Comment: maybe try console.log(this.imageUrls[1]);

Comment: @Igor Says undefined. I edited the post. Thx.

Comment: @Rabolf says undefined

Comment: This is duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323). You are calling through to `getImageUrl` which executes an async call and does further processing to add the image urls but the call to this method is synchronous and then assumes the image urls are immediately available. Read through this duplicate to better understand how you have to write code when dealing with asynchronous calls like http calls.

Comment: You are also clearing the imageUrls array every time the function is called.

Comment: it's weird if console.log(this.imageUrls); works and shows the array but console.log(this.imageUrls[1]); says undefined then maybe try foreach

Comment: Why are you subscribing in both constructor and `ngOnInit`? In general, keep such logic, especially asynchronous logic, out of the constructor. It is designed to initialize static variables, etc.

Comment: this.imageUrls.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
});

Comment: @mrsundquist Yes I did that. But dind't work.

Comment: @Rabolf I try it like you say but I don't have luck.

Comment: @torazaburo I'm reading and trying to understand that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You must make the 'getImagUrl' function synchronous. For example, you can do this by using Subject:

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

imgSelected: any;

ngOnInit() {   
    this.firebaseService.getListings().subscribe(listings => { 
      this.listings = listings;
      for(var i = 0;i<this.listings.length;i++){
        this.getImageUrl(listings[i].$key).subscribe(isObtained => {
          if (isObtained) {
            this.imgSelected = this.imageUrls[0].url;
          }
        });
      }
    });
 }

getImageUrl(prodid): Subject<boolean> {
    let subject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
    this.imageUrls = []; 
    this.firebaseService.getListingImages(prodid).subscribe(images => { 
      this.images = images[0];
      let image = images[0];
      let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
      let spaceRef = storageRef.child(image.path);
      storageRef.child(image.path).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
        // Set image url
        this.imageUrls.push(new ImageUrl(image.$key,url));
        subject.next(true);
        subject.complete();
      }).catch((error) => {
        subject.next(false);
        subject.complete();
        console.log(error);
      });        
    });
    return subject;
}
```

One image label:

```
<img class="img-responsive" [src]="imgSelected">
```

Using ngFor:

```
<img *ngFor="let img of imageUrls" class="img-responsive" [src]="img.url">
```

ngOnInit update:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.firebaseService.getListings().subscribe(listings => {
      let listingsLength = listings.length;
      let count: number = 0;
      let subject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
      subject.subscribe(finish => {
        listings.forEach(list => {
          list.url = this.imageUrls.find(img => img.id === list.$key).url;
        });
        this.listings = listings;
      });
      for (let i = 0; i < listingsLength; i++) {
        count++;
        this.getImageUrl(listings[i].$key).subscribe(isObtained => {
          if (count === listingsLength) {
            subject.next('complete');
            subject.complete();
          }
        });
      }
    });
 }
```

HTML Code:

> ```
> <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let listing of listings  | orderby:'!$key'"  >
>     <div class="card">
>         <div class="card-image">
>             <img class="img-responsive" [src]="listing.url">
>
>             <span class="card-title">{{listing.title}}</span>
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="card-content">
>             <p>Cards for display in portfolio style material design by Google.</p>
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="card-action">
>             <a [routerLink]="['/listing/'+listing.$key]">+ Info</a>
>             <a [routerLink]="['/listing/'+listing.$key]">Contacto</a>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: HI, thanx for the reply. I try what you say but I can´t access says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ImageUrl' of undefined. So I do this:             `                console.log(this.imageUrls[0].url);
         this.listings[0].src = this.imageUrls[0].url;
` and I get the first image url. If I do console.log show four times the url on my chrome console.

Comment: Sorry for the error, I have just corrected in ngOnInit how to access the object correctly. Look again at the contents of the subscription to 'getImageUrl'. =)

Comment: I want to do this: <img class="img-responsive" src="{{imageUrls[0].url}}"> on my front end (later I will change 0 for $index) but says: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined. I don't know why. You have idea?

Comment: Ah okay. I just edited the answer with the solution. Hope this can help you.

Comment: Now is showing always the same image. How I do this dynamic for each listing? I edit my post with full front end code. Please check it :). Thanks for this help.

Comment: Try with ngFor on img label.

Comment: Try this latest update in ngOnInit. You should also use the img with ngFor tag. Hope this can help you.

Comment: Ok that put all images on each listing. Don't detect who is for each listing. Hmm

Comment: Try last updated, HTML and ngOnInit code. I add the url attribute to each listing element.